# Navigation with hover reveal using Jquery or css3

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a navigation bar that reveals content on hover. You can see a working demo here:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjciG

As you can see, it works fairly well, but it is a bit buggy.

My jquery is simple and can definitely be improved:

```
$("#navButtons li").hover(function(){
     $(this).find("span#tooltip").stop().fadeIn(300);
}, function(){
     $(this).find("span#tooltip").stop().fadeOut(300);
});
```

The `span#tooltip` is absolutely placed BELOW the hover-able link, so when the user hovers over the link and then tries to hover over the tooltip/box it flickers (because there is a moment where the user is not hovering over anything). I need to allow the user to hover over an element, see the box fade in, and then allow the user to hover over the box and click on any links or content that might be within.

Is there a better way of writing this using Jquery OR CSS3 to achieve a smoother, more reliable result?

Comment: one workaround is to add a absolutely positioned div with a transparent background to fill that space, so the user never actually hovers off the  list item...but this is dirty. other thoughts?

Comment: Do **NOT**, never, no more use multiple ID's per page! Change `#tooltip` into a class!

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the CSS of the tooltip. Adding `padding-top:20px; margin-top:-20px` to `span#tooltip` makes the position of the tip as high as the icons; thus, there's no way to 'mouseout' of those links. And since the icons have a higher z than the tooltip, moving from icon to icon has no ill effect.

[image]

(outline added for illustrative purposes)

Comment: And change `id="tooltip"` to `class="tooltip"`

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternate way would be to use just CSS to achieve the fade in and out effect.

I put together a quick and dirty example [here](http://jsbin.com/iyozed/1/edit) to show how this could be done. There are obvious caveats that not all browsers support it, but the same could be said of users having javascript disabled in the current example. The CSS version would still work, it just would appear and disapper without fading.

Also just hiding the elements with opacity will make them more accessibility friendly.

Just another option :)

Answer (score 0):

Curiously I ran into the same problem with a pass project. The solution was adding a delay before hiding the *tooltip* using the javascript's `setTimeout` method.

Here is the code :

```
var closeTip = new Array();
$("#navButtons li").each(function (i) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(closeTip[i]); // cancell closing tooltip
    if ($this.hasClass('visible')) {
      return false; // we are still on, do nothing else
    } else {
      // we moved to another "li" element so reset everything
      $("#navButtons li").removeClass('visible');
      $("span.tooltip").hide(); 
    }
    // show "this" tooltip and add class "visible" as flag
    $this.addClass('visible').find("span.tooltip").stop().fadeIn(300).mouseenter(function () {
      clearTimeout(closeTip[i]); // cancell closing itself even if we leave 
    });
  },
  function () {
    // delay closing tooltip unless is cancelled by another mouseenter event
    closeTip[i] = setTimeout(function () {
      $this.removeClass('visible').find("span.tooltip").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }, 500);
  });
}); // each
```

Since you shouldn't use the same **ID** within the same document, I converted all `id="tooltip"` into `class="tooltip"`.

Also notice within the script that I am adding a `class="visible"` to the hovered element  and setting the same css property to that selector

```
#navButtons li.hours:hover span, #navButtons li.hours.visible span {
  background-position: -1px -35px;
}
#navButtons li.login:hover span, #navButtons li.login.visible span {
  background-position: -41px -35px;
}
#navButtons li.newsletter:hover span, #navButtons li.newsletter.visible span {
  background-position: -83px -35px;
}
```

... so the buttons won't flicker either when we move from them into the tooltip.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jgYtz/)**

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A26UX/3/)

You forgot just to add a single attribute to your **`#navButtons li span`** CSS selector.

```css
margin-bottom: 25px; /* 20px is the tooltip distance, but a little extra helps */
```

The reason why this works is because `margin-bottom` is part of the "box model" for which the `hover` event can monitor any state changes.  Also change your tooltip `id` so there **classnames** instead, as you can't have the same `id` twice on a webpage.